# How to Create a Certificate using MakeCert.exe with existing CA

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, self-signed, makecert

I need a Certificate for my local development purpose, the certificate should have a valid Issuer.

I tried [the following blog](https://ondrej.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/iis-7-and-client-certificates/) to create a Certificate.

In the blog I found a tool MakeCert.exe to create a Certificate but I can't able to bind any existing Certificate as a Root CA.

I used the Command `makecert -ss My -n "CN=DevRoot" -cy authority -in "John" Test.cer`

Finally the certificate has some issue

[image]

I need a Certificate and Issuer should be DevRoot.

[DevRoot.cer download URL](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Certificates/DevRoot.cer).

Kindly assist me in this regards.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not a programming question.

Comment: well, if that is needed to sign a ClickOnce deployed VS project ...

Answer (score 0):

in case it is still actual..
you don't need '-in' param, but should use '-r' because :
-r  Creates a self-signed certificate.

```
makecert -ss My -n "CN=DevRoot" -cy authority -r Test3.cer
```